# For what do I need the Socket::MSG_* constants in ruby?

Tags: ruby, sockets, network-programming, udp

I want to develop a p2p app which communicates via UDPSockets. I'm just starting to read the docs for that and I couldn't understand that piece of ruby's socket management.

Specifically it's possible to add those "flags", as ruby-doc calls them, to every send call. (http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/UDPSocket.html#method-i-send)

But when do I use those and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably know if you need to use them as you'll have an example or some documentation that refers to them.

Some of the more common options used with `recvfrom` are: `MSG_OOB` to process out-of-band data, `MSG_PEEK` to peek at the incoming message without de-queueing it, and `MSG_WAITALL` to wait for the receive buffer to fill up.

These are really quite edge-case so you probably won't ever see one used.

Those flags come from the low-level `recv` call on which `Socket` is based.